# object serialization while storing in database through ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I tried to store serialized object in console it is working fine but if I try it through application it raises TypeError.

In my model I declared as:

serialize :connection_string

while I was saving the object I am getting the following error

TypeError: allocator undefined for Proc
    from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:227:in `allocate'
    from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:227:in`revive'
    from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in`accept'
    from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
    from /home/nyros/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:228:in`block in revive'

Comment: serialize :connection_string,Array ...?

Comment: No, it is a custom ruby class (Appnexusapi::Connection)

Comment: Can you post your console output and the model code ?

Comment: console: 1.9.2p320:004> r = RequestTracker.last
  RequestTracker Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "request_trackers".* FROM "request_trackers" ORDER BY "request_trackers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<RequestTracker id: 9, scheduled_date_id: 7, get_count: 1, post_count: 0, report_count: 0, connection_time: nil, waiting_time: "2014-01-16 06:57:27", created_at: "2014-01-16 06:57:27", updated_at: "2014-01-16 06:57:39", get_carry: 0, post_carry: 0, get_time: "2014-01-16 06:57:27", post_time: "2014-01-16 06:57:27", connection_string: nil> 
1.9.2p320 :005 > a =  AppnexusApi::Connection.new({})
r.connection_string = a

Comment: IN my model:  serialize :connection_string